# BFS all paths to specific depth

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, breadth-first-search

I'm using networkx library to generate an undirected graph given the parent-child relationship. Given depth `x` and a starting point for the graph, I can find all the nodes at depth `x`, but I also want the path taken to get to that node. How do I collect nodes traversed while getting to the path?

Here is my code that gets me all the nodes at `depth <= x`

```
def descendants_at_distance(G, source, distance):
    if not G.has_node(source):
        raise nx.NetworkXError(f"The node {source} is not in the graph.")
    current_distance = 0
    current_layer = {source}
    visited = {source}
    layer_with_distance = {}

    while current_distance < distance:
        next_layer = set()
        for node in current_layer:
            # print(G[node])
            for child in G[node]:
                if child not in visited:
                    visited.add(child)
                    next_layer.add(child)
        current_layer = next_layer
        current_distance += 1
        layer_with_distance.update({current_distance: current_layer})
    
    layer_with_distance =  {key:val for (key, val) in layer_with_distance.items() if val}
    return layer_with_distance
```

The above code is modification to the inbuilt networkx library code since I need all the nodes between `depth = 1...x`

```
df_links = [(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,6),(3,9),(4,7),(4,8),(9,7),(9,10),(7,8),(7,10), (15,16)]
Graph = nx.Graph(df_links)
```

For example above if the `source = 1` and `distance = 3` the output should be
`{1: {2, 3, 4}, 2: {8, 9, 6, 7}, 3: {10}}` where `key = distance` and `value = nodes at distance`.

What I want with this is the nodes traversed at each key-value pair. For example, at `depth = 2` the nodes are `{8,9,6,7}` (order doesn't matter), and the traversed nodes for each are like this. `1-4-8, 1-3-9, 1-2-6, 1-4-7`

Let me know if any further clarification is needed.

Comment: Can you clarify your desired output... if you used the same example as you did for the current `distance=3` `source=1`, what would be the desired output or an easier example if that one has too much output?

Comment: If that isn't the formating you were hoping for let me know and I can change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:  I added another dictionary that collected each stop along the way and the ouput is identical to what you said it would be
(see the bottom for the output)

```py
...
    ...
    layer_with_distance = {}
    tracker = {} # added this
    while current_distance < distance:
        tracker[source] = {} # added this
        next_layer = set()
        for node in current_layer:
            # print(G[node])
            tracker[source][node] = []  # added this
            for child in G[node]:
                if child not in visited:
                    tracker[source][node].append(child) #added this
                    visited.add(child)
                    next_layer.add(child)
        current_layer = next_layer
        current_distance += 1
        layer_with_distance.update({current_distance: current_layer})

    layer_with_distance =  {key:val for (key, val) in layer_with_distance.items() if val}
    return layer_with_distance, tracker # added to this


df_links = [(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,6),(3,9),(4,7),(4,8),(9,7),(9,10),(7,8),(7,10), (15,16)]
Graph = nx.Graph(df_links)
print(descendants_at_distance(Graph, 1, 2))
```

output

```py
layer_with_distance: {1: {2, 3, 4}, 2: {8, 9, 6, 7}}

tracker: {1: {2: [6], 3: [9], 4: [7, 8]}}
```